# Induction on integers in Lean creates non-int types

Tags: types, type-conversion, induction, lean

I want to use induction on an integer variable, doing an inductive step both in the positive and negative direction.

Consider the following theorem (for demonstration, no matter if it makes sense):

```
theorem exmpl (x : ℤ) : (x = 5):=
begin
  induction x,
  -- inductive steps
end
```

which produces in Leans tactic state:

```
case int.of_nat
x: ℕ
⊢ int.of_nat x = 5

case int.neg_succ_of_nat
x: ℕ
⊢ -[1+ x] = 5
```

Reasonably, the induction produces two cases, one for the positive and one for the negative direction. But what also happens is that x has now become a natural number and in the goals it changed to `int.of_nat x` and `-[1+ x]`.

As my induction operates inside of the integers, I would assume that those types are some kind of „subset“ of them, presumably having more useful properties than integers. The [Lean Reference](https://leanprover.github.io/reference/expressions.html) states that the second one seems to be „an implicit argument that should be inferred by type class resolution”, without explaining further what that means.

While this conversion is probably necessary for certain applications, in my use case I just want to continue working with integers and have not found a good way to convert the goals back to using integers.

So my questions are:

- What are those new types `x` was converted to, what do they mean and why does the conversion make sense?
- And, more important: How do I change the goal back to a case where I can work with integers again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The induction tactic in Lean uses an induction principle based on the definition of the type. For the natural numbers, this induction principle is the well known one. For the integers, the definition is slightly non intuitive and gives a not very useful induction principle.

In Lean the integers are defined as the disjoint union of two copies of the natural numbers. This gives you two functions from nat to int, the canonical embedding sending n to n, and another map sending n to -(n + 1). Every integer is uniquely of the form n or -(n + 1) for n a natural number, and the induction principle for integers basically considers these two cases, which is not that useful. In Lean these two maps nat to int are called `int.of_nat` and `int.neg_succ_of_nat`, and `-[1+ x]`  is notation for `int.neg_succ_of_nat`.

So although `induction` turned `x` into a natural number, `int.of_nat x` and `-[1+ x]` are still both integers.

If you want a more useful way of inducting on integers you could use the theorem `int.induction_on` defined in `data.int.basic` in mathlib https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/data/int/basic.html You might be able to use this by importing this file (there are docs about imstalling and importing mathlib files on the mathlib website) and using `induction x using int.induction_on` (this method doesn't always work) or something like `apply int.induction_on x` or `refine int.induction_on x _ _ _` might also work.

It's also worth mentioning that it's fairly rare to use induction when working with integers in Lean and mostly you just use the library theorem to prove most of what you want.

Answer (score 2):

To add on a little to Christopher Hughes answer, the `int` type is defined in the Lean 3 core as:

```
inductive int : Type
| of_nat : nat → int
| neg_succ_of_nat : nat → int
```

See [here](https://github.com/leanprover-community/lean/blob/89e98b56713c027afdf97ad96abd2d54b35a43d5/library/init/data/int/basic.lean#L15-L17).

The `induction` tactic (i.e., `induction x`) works the same as `cases x` when the `inductive` type in question is not recursive, which `int` is not -- neither of its constructors (ex. `of_nat` and `neg_succ_of_nat`) take an `int` as an argument (the type only appears as an output). Thus, to prove something holds for `int` in Lean, you prove that holds for each of these cases (with no additional induction hypotheses). However, as Christopher Hughes noted, a lot of common properties and theorems about `int` have already been proven and are available in either the Lean 3 core library itself or in mathlib. You can then use these theorems as building blocks instead to prove more complex concepts.